# pagePath dimensions yielding unexpected results from API queries in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to use the GA API to run session queries that exclude certain page paths. I've tried using the following dimensions with varying levels of success, but am generally confused by the results.

**pagePath**

**pagePathLevel1**

**pagePathLevel2**

**pagePathLevel3**

Queries excluding visits based on **pagePathLevel1** and **pagePathLevel2** seem to yield expected results, but as soon as I use **pagePathLevel3** it starts acting weird.

Example:

```
ga:pagePathLevel3==/page1/ yields no results

ga:pagePathLevel3==/page1/
```

yields the following:

```
 desktop    882
  mobile    124
  tablet    38
```

Queries using regex and pagePath also act weird.

Example:

```
ga:pagePath=~/page/.*
```

yields the same result as

```
ga:pagePathLevel3!~/page/.*
```

I looked through Stack and the GA API docs and coudln't find anything useful on the subject. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I also tried including the hostname as a filter in conjunction with the pagePath dimensions with no improvement.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce what you're seeing. Can you share a report from the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) with your configuration?

Comment: Sure thing! http://i.imgur.com/CIxBkK5.jpg

Comment: Why are you even using the PagePathLevel* dimensions?  Can't you just use filters on ga:PagePath?

Comment: I was having issues with those queries as well as I would have to either use a contains argument with the overall pagepath filter or more complex regex. I'd like to include all traffic as long as the 3 level page path = x. Seems like this is exactly what this dimensions was designed to do.